# 443: Timed out when Pushing to VSTS in VS

Tags: git, azure-devops

What I am trying to do? Pushing to VSTS my local repository changes. I am getting errors.

### Steps to Replicate issue

1. Connect to my VSTS repository in VS
2. Click on Sync
3. Click on Push

[Error in VS when Perfoming a Push Action to VSTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nnzuh.png)

*To get through the above error message I set the proxy i.e. git config --global http.proxy http://username:pwd@url:8080. [Stackflow troubleshoot article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44285651/set-proxy-for-microsoft-git-provider-in-visual-studio)*

4. Set the proxy as above command and run through 1-3 steps again.
5. Prompts me to sign into GIT and I git it my email address to authenticate using OKTA.
6. Finishes signing in
7. I get the below error message

[Error Message after OKTA signs me in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0VN2.png)

Reaching out to the community to see if anyone knows how to troubleshoot this issue, and possibly get around the proxy issue i.e. Not having to set the proxy all the time?

Comment: Do you need to use proxy to connect to VSTS? What's the result if you push changes to VSTS through git push command directly?

Comment: I do not need proxy to connect to VSTS only when I pull, push or clone from or to there. I'll give that a go through the command but when I have done it previously I have been presented the same result.

Comment: Do you mean the same issue with git command? How do you clone repository? Git command or VS?

Comment: Yes same issue with Git command, I use my personal network to download outside my corporate one. VS

Comment: How do you download the source?