# VS2017 Git fails to clone with Proxy CONNECT aborted error

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

Trying to clone a repo from git under VSTS in Visual Studio 2017 but get the following error:

```
 Git failed with a fatal error. 
 unable to access https://myaccount.visualstudio.com/_git/MyProject/: 
 Proxy CONNECT aborted
```

Am in a corporate environment with a proxy in place for internet access.
Have tried setting the defaultProxy setting in system.net in the devenv.exe.config but makes no difference.

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
    <proxy proxyaddress="http://proxyurl:8080" bypassonlocal="True" />
</defaultProxy>
```

Visual Studio 2015 works without issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio 2017 uses the Git commandline, 2015 uses LibGit2. You'll need to configure the proxy in your Git global settings as well now:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3406766/736079

Comment: Thanks. I also found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44285651/set-proxy-for-microsoft-git-provider-in-visual-studio to be useful